# How can I create multiple objects and track them efficiently?

Tags: java

I have to make a console application (game) as a university project. We started learning Java this semester, never used OOP before this semester. In this game we play as an explorer and have to complete 5 maps which are generated randomly.

I got a tile object which should be an 1*1 randomly generated tile form a Size * Size (user input) map. And I have to do it 5 times since there are 5 maps we can explore in the game.

My problem comes when I have to generate unknown amount of tile objects (and have to track each of them (where are they on a map, and which map they belong to)). How can I do that efficiently?

Comment: You have tried something ? What is your plan ? I don't see what is the problem you have. PS: don't try to thing about efficiency for the moment !

Comment: Please read up on java `arrays` and the `Collections` framework

Comment: More precisely you will want a nested array or list (`Cell[][]` / `List<List<Cell>>`). Both lists and arrays are iterable and indexable and using nesting structures help representing the two dimensions easily.

Comment: Why are you worried about efficiency? Just do the simplest thing that could possibly work. If it proves to be inefficient, *then* you'll have a specific problem to solve.